# Find record of unauthorized domain logon on 2003 domain controller

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory

My manager wants to know who has logged in as him from his PC or any other PC and sent an email. The DC is a Windows 2003 server and the workstation is Windows 7. Is there there any utility that can do that? I have tried the Windows security event log on the DC.

Comment: Do you know what machine or group of machines where the incident might have occurred? I would try to narrow the scope of it down to just a few machines, and with the date stamp on the email, view the Security Audit logs around that time on each machine. You might find it, but proving who was behind the keyboard will be more difficult...

Answer (score 0):

Probably not.

If it's not in the Security Event Log now, then you either didn't log it, or the log has been overwritten since.  Either way, your chances aren't good.

If you have good backups, you could maybe restore an older copy of the Security Log an search through it, but based on... well, let's just say my gut's telling me you probably don't have backups of your decade-old server which you don't know the logging level on.  And, of course, if you don't have the required logging level set, then the data just never existed to begin with.